# Can't upload file to firebase storage. Keep showing 'E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred. An unknown error occurred..'

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

[image]

Error whenever I try to upload any file:
[image]

Code for uploading image to storage:

```
    private void uploadFileToStorage(String uid,String[] data){
    StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("idiot");
    ref.putFile(noticeUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot ->
                    ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                        showUploadMessage(100,"Saving to database...");
                        dismissMainDialog();
                        //saveToDatabase(uid,data,String.valueOf(uri));
                    }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        dismissMainDialog();
                        showSnackBar("Failed to save in database");
                    })
            ).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                dismissMainDialog();
                showSnackBar(e.getMessage());
            }).addOnProgressListener(snapshot -> {
                int percent = (int)(snapshot.getBytesTransferred()/snapshot.getTotalByteCount())*100;
                showUploadMessage(percent,null);
            });
}
```

Added dependencies are

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

I don't know where is the problem. I have also updated `google-service.json` after creating bucket.
**Not working even after creating new project & adding dependencies**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Google Cloud [Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/)
2. Go to IAM & Admin
   [image]
3. Click on ADD, and in New principals add `firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com` and set the Role as `Storage Admin` and click Save
   [image]
4. Wait for few minutes, then problem should be solved